# How to async await in react render function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I am pretty much familiar with the `async await` but with back end `nodejs`. But there is a scenario came across to me where I have to use it on front end.

I am getting array of objects and in that objects I am getting `lat lng` of the places. Now using `react-geocode` I can get the place name for a single `lat lng` but I want to use that inside the map function to get the places names. SO as we know it `async` call I have to use `async await` over there.

Here is the code

```
import Geocode from "react-geocode";
render = async() => {
  const {
    phase,
    getCompanyUserRidesData
  } = this.props   
                      
  return (
    <div>
       <tbody>                   
        await Promise.all(_.get(this.props, 'getCompanyUserRidesData', []).map(async(userRides,index) => {
          const address = await Geocode.fromLatLng(22.685131,75.873468)
          console.log(address.results[0].formatted_address)                         
         return ( 
          <tr key={index}>
            <td>
            {address.results[0].formatted_address}
            </td>
            <td>Goa</td>
            <td>asdsad</td>
            <td>{_.get(userRides,'driverId.email', '')}</td>
            <td>{_.get(userRides,'driverId.mobile', '')}</td>
          </tr>
        )
        }))
      </tbody>
    </div>
  )
}
```

But when I use async with the map function here it doesn't return anything. Can anyone please help me where I going wrong?

Comment: `render` function renders UI to the browser, so that is not the place you want to do your asynchronous calls

Comment: So is there any other way to work around?

Comment: @Profer yes. Have it be state on a parent component that conditionally renders the child once the state is set (i.e. the asynchronous data comes in). That's pretty standard in any React app and IIRC is early on in the official tutorial (I may be misremembering that).

Comment: @JaredSmith could you please show an example. BTW what is IIRC?

Comment: @Profer If I Remember Correctly

Comment: Why don't you map through `getCompanyUserRidesData`, and return a component that renders the `tr`? Then that component can implement `componentDidMount` to make the `Geocode.fromLatLng` request. You shouldn't be making network requests in your `render`

Comment: @Galupuf yes I tried that but still no luck.

Comment: That should be working for you. Maybe consider asking another question regarding the issues you're having with the different approach. The moral of this question is you shouldn't be doing async calls in `render`

Comment: @Profer example added.

Comment: Hope [this](https://ja.reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data) can be helpful.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

You should always separate concerns like fetching data from concerns like displaying it. Here there's a parent component that fetches the data via AJAX and then conditionally renders a pure functional child component when the data comes in.

```
class ParentThatFetches extends React.Component {
  constructor () {
    this.state = {};
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    fetch('/some/async/data')
      .then(resp => resp.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({data}));
  }

  render () {
    {this.state.data && (
      <Child data={this.state.data} />
    )}
  }
}

const Child = ({data}) => (
  <tr>
    {data.map((x, i) => (<td key={i}>{x}</td>))}
  </tr>
);
```

I didn't actually run it so their may be some minor errors, and if your data records have unique ids you should use those for the key attribute instead of the array index, but you get the jist.

### UPDATE

Same thing but simpler and shorter using hooks:

```
const ParentThatFetches = () => {
  const [data, updateData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      const resp = await fetch('some/url');
      const json = await resp.json()
      updateData(json);
    }
    getData();
  }, []);

  return data && <Child data={data} />
}
```

Answer (score 4):

With the wrapper function below, **delayed_render()**, you can write asynchronous code inside a React component function:

```
function delayed_render(async_fun, deps=[]) {
    const [output, setOutput] = useState()
    useEffect(async () => setOutput(await async_fun()), deps)
    return (output === undefined) ? null : output
}
```

This wrapper performs delayed rendering: it returns `null` on initial rendering attempt (to skip rendering of this particular component), then asynchronously calculates (useEffect()) the proper rendering output through a given `async_fun()` and invokes re-rendering to inject the final result to the DOM. The use of this wrapper is as simple as:

```
function Component(props) {
    return delayed_render(async () => { /* any rendering code with awaits... */ })
}
```

For example:

```
function Component(props) {
    return delayed_render(async () => {
        const resp = await fetch(props.targetURL)     // await here is OK!
        const json = await resp.json()
        return <Child data={json} />
    })
}
```

UPDATE: added the `deps` argument. If your `async_fun` depends on props or state variables, all of them must be listed in `deps` to allow re-rendering. Note that passing `deps=null` (*always re-render*) is not an option here, because the `output` is a state variable, too, and would be implicitly included in dependencies, which would cause infinite re-rendering after the `async_fun` call completes.

This solution was inspired by, and is a generalization of, the Jared Smith's one.