# React - calling async function from render()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await

I am trying to write my first React app and it is supposed to generate QR codes for different inputs and display them on a web page.

I already have my own 'library' function that does this thing for me - I only pass the data as a parameter and it returns a promise of data URL that I use as an src for an image and it's done. Here is how it works now:

```
class App extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            dataUrl: '',
        }
    }

    async componentDidMount(){
        let url = await getDataURL('<some imaginary static data>');
        this.setState({dataUrl: url});
    }

    render() {
        return(
            <div className="App">
                <div>
                    <img alt="" src={this.state.dataUrl} style={{height: 200 + 'px', width: 200 + 'px'}} />
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

But now I need to call `getDataURL()` multiple times for some real data, e.g. I might have multiple `<div>`'s with different data and I need to get and render the QR code for each of them.

If I had a function, something like this:

```
async loadQRCode(data){
    let url = await getDataURL(data);
    return url;
}
```

Is there any way how to call it for each data directly from `render()` function? Or is there any better approach that I am missing?

Comment: Don't call functions from `render()`. What you do is a) update your `state` (using as many async operations as you like) and b) render() the state. a) and b) happen independently, and since React re-renders whenever the state changes, all render() needs to do is render the *current* state; it doesn't have to worry about anything else. So if you have multiple QR codes, use an array for them in your state.

Comment: @ChrisG he has a function `loadQRCode` which returns an image url and this is good to use it in a render.

Comment: @TheReason Even if the function is async? I'm looking at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53820246/5734311). It will work I guess, I'm just wondering if it's good practice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would like to say that `componentDidMount` function is a `static` function.

But you can have an async function like `loadQRCode` where you can call the function and iterate the `API` calls and push the result into and `array` and then you can render the `div`'s with the required data.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried something like this?

```
// some code before
this.state.listOfImages.map((image, i) =>
  <div>
    <img
      alt=""
      src={this.loadQRCode(image.src)}
      style={{height: 200 + 'px', width: 200 + 'px'}}
    />
  </div>

)
// some code after
```

You might need to bind a `getDataURL` method in a `constructor

Comment: But doesn't this recalculate all the QR code dataURLs on each render?

Answer (score 0):

It's good to call API requests in `componentDidMount`. Then you can call `setState` after that.

```
async componentDidMount(){
        const result = await loadQRCode(`your params`);
        this.setState({ result });
    }
```

Comment: OP knows to do that. I don't see what this answer offers in terms of the question that was asked?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this using an array of objects in constructor:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        qrCodeData: [
            {
                data: <data>
                qrcode: ''
            },
            {
                data: <data>
                qrcode: ''
            },
            ...
        ]
    }
}
```

and in `componentDidMount()` I iterate over the array and call my `getDataURL()` function to set `qrcode`.

```
async componentDidMount(){
    let qrCodeDataCopy = this.state.qrCodeData.slice();
    for (let item of qrCodeDataCopy) {
        item.qrcode = await getDataURL(item.data);
    }
    this.setState({qrCodeData: qrCodeDataCopy});
}
```