# Fetch Request response.json() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, fetch, fetch-api

I want to fetch a get request to my spring boot server, and i get my json back, but when i want to return it, there is an undefined error. I am new to Javascript, so the answer is probably obvious, but i cant find it!

Sry for bad english and thanks in regards!

Code:

```
function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    fetch(theUrl,
    {
        method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then (response => response.json())
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response); // Logs the json array
        return response; // Returns undefined
    });
}
```

Edit with async, still does not work:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

```
async function httpGet(theUrl)
{
    const response = await fetch(theUrl,
    {
        method: "GET",
        headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    });
    const jsonResponse = await response.json()
    .then(data => {
        return data;
    });
}
```

This is my react component function:

```
 function Admin(){
    const data =  httpGet('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users'); // Not Working
    console.log(data);  
    return(
        <div>
            <h1> Admin Page</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: return the `fetch` itself. write down `return fetch (theurl, ...)` like that.

Comment: This returns a pending with the value of undefined

Comment: This return a promise, so you need to use `async` `await` for that. learn more about it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Asynchronous/Async_await

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function httpGet(theUrl) {
  return fetch(theUrl, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    })
    .then(response => response.json());
}


(async() => {
  const response = await httpGet('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
  console.log(response);
})();
```

Comment: Sry for asking again, but how do i get the response data out of this async function to add it to the render in react?

Comment: You just need to call this line and assign the result to a variable `await httpGet('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users')`. I've used a `async` immediately invoked function here just to showcase a working code. If you still need help, please feel free to create a separate question with your `react` code in it so that the community can help you better.

Comment: In react i am using a simple component function to render my json output, but i cant call the httpGet function with await, because the component function isnt async

Comment: This already has a lot of answers, as I can see on SO. namely, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819864/how-to-async-await-in-react-render-function), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57206872/what-happens-if-we-call-an-async-function-inside-render-method) & [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57052788/react-calling-async-function-from-render)

Comment: Ah, thanks for your time, i will look into it

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with `async` and `await` which makes easy to write and understand the code.

Here is the sample, that you can use.

```js
const httpGet = async (theUrl) => {
  const response = await fetch(theUrl, {
    method: "GET",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  });
  return response.json();
};

// calling the method

(async () => {
  const data = await httpGet("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1")
  console.log("response data is: ", data)
})()
```