# Objects are not valid as a React child when trying to map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to fetch data from my api and render it as a list but it keeps giving me the error mentionned in the title.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./style/list.css";
import { getEvents } from "../services/eventService";
import { thisExpression } from "@babel/types";

class Likes extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      events: []
    };
  }
  async componentWillMount() {
    const { data: events } = await getEvents();
    this.setState({ events });
    console.log(events);
  }

  async getUserLikes() {
    // Get Likes TODO
    return 1;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <ul class="list-group">
          {this.state.events.map(event => (
            <li
              class="list-group-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center"
              key={event._id}
            >
              {event.title}
              <span class="badge badge-primary badge-pill">
                {this.getUserLikes()}
              </span>
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Likes;
```

Weirdly enough though , it seems when i remove the getUserLikes() function from the render the mapping works but when i add it, it doesn't.

Comment: Is this the real code for `getUserLikes`? Or you are performing a request from it?

Comment: it was a request at first but i removed it to see where the problem came from . Even with getUserLikes like this it doesn't work but once removed it works

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819864/how-to-async-await-in-react-render-function

Comment: If you remove the `async` flag and just return `1` it will work. But for your real use case it won't

Comment: Have you, by chance, examined [official tutorials](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html) on the subject?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `getUserLikes` is `async`.

When calling a function as `async`, it will return a Promise object, which isn't a renderable.

If you want to call some function inside `render`, it can't be `async`.

Even if `getUserLikes` doesn't call an async request, if you add `async` in front of it, it will return a `promise` object.

You can see this behavior in the example bellow.

```js
async function call1() { return 1; }

function call2() { return 1; }

// Promise Object
console.log(call1())
// Actual returned value
console.log(call2())
```

If you want to fetch data and render it, you should fetch it in `componentDidMount`, not inside render.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the `async` nature of your handler. The returned statement of a component must be pure. You can't declare imperative code inside a `jsx` block.

Usually in cases like that you want to declare a local state which eventually gets filled with the returned data and acts like a placeholder until then.

```
const Component = () =>{
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)

    useEffect(() =>{
        fetch(/*..*/).then(response => setData(response))
    },[])

    return data ? data.map(/*...*/) : <div> Loading </div>
}
```