# Can't await promise in map method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-context

I'm trying to render a list of rooms and then get the user data of each recipient in the room, and since there only can be 2 users in the room (you + the other person), the recipient is just the other person.

```
async renderRooms(room, user) {
    const recipentId = room.users.filter(id => id != user.id)[0],
        recipients = await userService.getOne(recipentId);

    console.log(recipients)

    return (
        <ListGroupItem tag="a" href="#" data-unread="3" action key={room._id} onClick={this.onRoomOpened.bind(this, room._id)}>
            <img src={""} />
            <div className="details">
                <div className="recipient-name"></div>
                <div className="last-message">
                    <MessageCircle className="feather" />
                    This is an example last message...
                </div>
            </div>
        </ListGroupItem>
    );
}

render() {
    if(this.props.rooms.length < 1) return <LoadingPage />;

    return (
        <userContext.Consumer>
        {({user}) => {
            if(this.state.roomId) return <ActiveRoom id={this.state.roomId} />;
            else
                return (
                    <ListGroup className="recipients">
                        {this.props.rooms.map(room => this.renderRooms(room, user))}
                    </ListGroup>
                );
        }}
        </userContext.Consumer>
    );
}
```

This way I filter out my own user ID from the user array, and then I take the remaining ID and use a promise to get the user data for it. But the problem here is that whenever I call `await` it throws the error:

> react-dom.development.js:14748 Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid
>   as a React child (found: [object Promise]). If you meant to render a
>   collection of children, use an array instead.

If I try to use `.then()` it actually doesn't seem to be called at all, as in, if I put a `console.log` in there, it prints out nothing.
Any idea how I can accomplish my task?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to async await in react render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819864/how-to-async-await-in-react-render-function)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't call an async function in the `render` method.

Async functions returns a Promise object, so this

```
{this.props.rooms.map(room => this.renderRooms(room, user))}
```

Will return an array of Promise Objects and you can't render and Object.

You need to call your async function in `componentDidMount` and render it when the data is loaded.

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819864/how-to-async-await-in-react-render-function) for an example of what to do.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation!