# Render React component asynchronously (wait for data to be returned)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following ReactJS **component**:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';

import {utility} from "./utility";

function Chart() {
    
    const [use_data, setData] = useState([]);

    const handleClick = () => {
        const newData = {
            x: ['giraffes', 'orangutans', 'monkeys'],
            y: [20, 14, 23],
            type: 'bar'
        }
        setData((use_data) => [...use_data, newData]);
    };

    return (
        <>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>GO</button>
        <Plot
            var data = {use_data}
            var layout={ {width: 1000, height: 400, title: "Top 100 Topics"} }
        />
        </>
    );

}

export default Chart;
```

It updates the hardcoded data to produce the following chart on button click:

[image]

Obviously I need to fetch my own data rather than hardcode it as above. In my utilites.js I produce data with the same structure shown above (newData), however it takes about a second to return this data. Thus, React does not render the visual.

ReactJS is obviously looking for some kind of asynchronous state management in order to render this visual (render once data are returned).

```
const handleClick = () => {
    const newData = utilities.fetch_data()
    setData((use_data) => [...use_data, newData]);
};
```

How can my above code be changed to allow for asynchonous rendering. Is this where a hook is needed to implement something similar to componentDidMount but for functional components?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to async await in react render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819864/how-to-async-await-in-react-render-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the problem correctly, you should use `Promise` when fetching data, after that, you need a utility to format the response something like the following example:

```
const formatter = (statics) => {
  const tmp = statics.map((static) => {name: static.name, .......});

  return tmp;
};

function App() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(null);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://blahblahblah.com')
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((response) => {
        return formatter(response.data.statics);
      })
      .then((formatedData) => setState(formatedData));
  }, []);

  return <h1>{state ? JSON.stringify(state) : "wait..."}</h1>;
}
```