# react-native@0.63.4 | react@17.0.1 deduped invalid - Causing Invalid Hook Call

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm making an android app in react native and get this error when using `useState` in a util file:
**Error**

```
WARN Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 287):
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
```

Trying to fix the error I ran `npm ls react`, which resulted in me getting this:

```
mobile_app@1.0.0 C:\...\mobile_app
+-- @react-native-community/masked-view@0.1.10
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid
+-- @react-navigation/native@5.9.3
| +-- @react-navigation/core@5.15.2
| | `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
+-- @react-navigation/stack@5.14.3
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
+-- expo@40.0.1
| +-- expo-asset@8.2.1
| | `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
| +-- expo-error-recovery@1.4.0
| | `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
| +-- expo-file-system@9.3.0
| | `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
| +-- expo-font@8.4.0
| | `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
| +-- expo-keep-awake@8.4.0
| | `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
| +-- expo-linear-gradient@8.4.0
| | `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
| +-- expo-permissions@10.0.0
| | `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
| `-- expo-sqlite@8.5.0
|   `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
+-- react-dom@17.0.1
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
+-- react-native-eva-icons@1.3.1
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid
+-- react-native-reanimated@1.13.2
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
+-- react-native-safe-area-context@3.1.9
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
+-- react-native-screens@2.18.0
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
+-- react-native-svg@12.1.0 invalid
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
+-- react-native-web@0.15.0
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
+-- react-native@0.63.4
| +-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid
| `-- use-subscription@1.5.1
|   `-- react@17.0.1 deduped
+-- react-test-renderer@16.13.1
| `-- react@17.0.1 deduped invalid
`-- react@17.0.1 invalid

npm ERR! code ELSPROBLEMS
npm ERR! invalid: react@17.0.1 C:\...\mobile_app\node_modules\react

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\...\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2021-03-02T12_38_31_428Z-debug.log
```

This is only a warning but when getting 1000+ in a minute, I am interested in stopping this from happening and correcting the invalid versions of react.

EDIT:

Below is the code I use to call the hook.
**util/wifiScanner.js**

```
import React, {useState}  from 'react';

import PermissionsAndroid from "react-native";
import WifiManager from "react-native-wifi-reborn";


const requestFineLocationPermission = async () => {

    ....

};

export async function getBeacons(props){

    await requestFineLocationPermission();

    const [wifiList, setWifiList] = useState(/* initialValue */); // you may provide an initial value (optional, defaults to undefined)

    WifiManager.setEnabled(true);
    WifiManager.reScanAndLoadWifiList().then((data) => {
        // update the state here
        setWifiList(data);
    });
    return wifiList;
};
```

The function getBeacons is called on the main screen here:
**screens/mainscreen.js**

```
import React, {useState}  from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, PermissionsAndroid, Linking, View, TouchableOpacity  } from 'react-native';
import { IndexPath, Layout, Text, Button, Select, SelectItem } from '@ui-kitten/components';
import { Icon } from 'react-native-eva-icons';

import {styles} from '../styles'
import WifiManager from "react-native-wifi-reborn";

import {getBeacons} from '../../util/wifiScanner';


const MainScreen = async ({navigation}) => {

    let list = await getBeacons(); // Currently throws {_U, _V, _W, _X} error

    return (

        <Layout style={styles.container}>

            ...

        </Layout>
    );
}

export default MainScreen;
```

Comment: It *might* be mismatched/multiple versions of React (I've seen it happen *once*) but it's way more likely that you actually have an invalid hook call. Post your code.

Comment: Those invalid matches that you have is because those packages still rely on `react@16.x.x`. `react-native@0.63.4` seems to "pin" `react` to `16.13.1`.

Comment: @JaredSmith I have added the code that calls the hook

Comment: @UnknownPerson that's an invalid hook call, just like the error says. You can only call hooks from other hooks or function components. You also [can't have an async component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819864/how-to-async-await-in-react-render-function/53820246#53820246).

Comment: @JaredSmith So I have to have the getBeacons function in ```const MainScreen``` ? Are you able to show an example of how the async would work ?

Comment: @UnknownPerson what you need to do, and I mean no offense, we all start somewhere, is work through some React tutorials. You seem to not really understand how it works. You can't have an async function component. You can't call side-effective functions outside of a `useEffect` hook. You can't call hooks in random Javascript functions. There is data about basically all of this in the [official tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html). If this is for a code bootcamp or a class, you may want to have a chat with your instructor, seems like they may have thrown you to the wolves...

Comment: ... without enough guidance or instruction. That answer I linked in my earlier comment pretty much gives you the outline of how to fetch and render async data, see the second section where it uses hooks.