# JS & React Trying to <div> from function but it states nothing was returned from render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

```js
export function Login() {
    window.addEventListener('load', function () {
        window.FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
            if (!response.authResponse) {
                console.log(response);
                return (
                    <div id='flex flex-row justify-center pb-100 fb-root'>
                        <button className='btn btn-round btn-lg'>Login</button>
                    </div>
                );
            } else {
                console.log('UserLoggedIn');
                return (
                    <div id='flex flex-row justify-center pb-100 fb-root'>
                        <button className='btn btn-round btn-lg'>Logout</button>
                    </div>
                );
            }
        });
    });
}
```

I am having trouble returning my button that either has login or logout depending on the response. I am using the window load function to ensure my other scripts have run first.

Error Message:

```
"react-dom.development.js:14169 Uncaught Error: Login(...): Nothing was returned from render. This usually means a return statement is missing. Or, to render nothing, return null."
```

Comment: As the error says, `Login` is not returning anything. `div` is returned in the callback

Comment: Because you're only returning some JSX _once_ `getLoginStatus` has been satisfied.

Comment: So how do I get Login to return the div from the other callback?

Comment: 1. If you're using `addEventListener` in React and you aren't **absolutely 100% sure you know *exactly* what you're doing**, *you're doing it wrong*. In your case you're *at best* leaking memory every time that component renders. 2. You can't perform arbitrary side-effects in a function component. Use hooks or the life-cycle methods of a class component. 3. Don't mix [data fetching with presentation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53820246/3757232). All of this is covered in [the official tutorial](https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html).

Comment: Thank you, I am very new to React and JS and Ive done a couple of tutorials I'm just trying to do a project to help me understand it all - which is a lot lol!

Comment: @LoganDallalio "which is a lot lol!" yes, yes it is also lol. No joke. React is a great framework for medium-to-large teams of experienced professional developers, but it's not really made for people new to coding. I know people try to learn it first and they try to teach it at bootcamps and such because hot tech == teh jobz, but it just wasn't made for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that this function is supposed to be a React component. React components need to return something. Your component is not returning anything. Based on the code above, it looks like you only want to render the button once you have a login status. So firstly return null from this function outside of window.addEventListener callback function. This will make the error go away, but will not accomplish what you are trying to do. Next, add an isLoading state to the component using the [useState](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) hook which defaults to true. Then, wrap your widow.addEventListener call inside a [useEffect](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) call and instead of returning the button, change the isLoading state to false. You will probably need a second state object to hold the result of the getLoginStatus. Then your component can conditionally return either of the buttons or null depending on the state of the component.