# Async function doesn't return in React app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I have an async function in a file (`someFile.js`) in my React app and I want the returned string from that function (`someFunction`) to be inserted in the webpage when it's finished. The problem is with the code below, I think the webpage loads before the promise is resolved, so the webpage appears blank. Can someone help me and see if there's a problem with my code below? The code below works when `someFunction` isn't an async function.

#### index.js

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App.js';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals.js';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

#### App.js

```js
import Header from "./components/Header.js";

function App() {
    return (
        <div className="container">
            <Header />
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

#### Header.js

```js
import someFunction from "./someFile.js";

const Header = () => {
    let text = someFunction();
    return (<h1>{text}</h1>)
}

export default Header;
```

#### someFile.js

```js
const someFunction = async () => {
    let x = await someAsyncFunc();
    return x; //x is a string
}

export default someFunction;
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to async await in react render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819864/how-to-async-await-in-react-render-function)  Hint: use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) to render the result of an async function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside Header.js

```
import {useEffect,useState} from "react";
import someFunction from "./someFile.js";

const Header = () => {
      const [text, setText] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    someFunction()
      .then((data) => setText(data))
      .catch((err) => console.log(err));
  }, []);

    return (<h1>{text}</h1>)
}

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember the concept of immutability in React.js, you should do something like this:

```
  import someFunction from "./someFile.js";

 import { useState, useEffect, useCallback } from ‘react’;

 const Header = () => {
   const [text, setText] = useState(‘’);

   const getApiText = useCallback(async () => {
     let apiReturnText = await someFunction();
     setText(apiReturnText);
   }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
      getApiText(); 
    }, [getApiText])

    return (<h1>{text}</h1>)
}

export default Header;
```

Comment: this code won't work well either, because `getApiText` is redefined on each render so the `useEffect` will be called on each render too - hence continually. Either make the dependency array of the `useEffect` empty (if you don't mind linter warnings about missing dependencies) or better, wrap `getApiText` in `useCallback` so it doesn't change.

Comment: You're right Robin, i thought `useCallback` is going to make things a little bit hard to understand, but i forgot the problem that you bring, thanks for pointing that! I've already fix