# In react native, I'm trying to save an object in AsyncStorage, but my app throws an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, local

I just want to save a simple object into a local storage using AsyncStorage, but my app throws an error saying "[SyntaxError: JSON Parse error: Unexpected identifier "object"]"

Here are my codes:

```
import forSaving from "./forSaving";

function About() {
  const obj = { id: 1, word: "This is a word" };

  const test = forSaving.store("test", obj);

  const getTest = forSaving.get(test);
  console.log(getTest);
}
export default About;
```

My goal is just to console.log(getTest) here.

And below, this is a reusable component for AsyncStorage, which I have just copied from a course by Mosh.
So, here, nothing should be wrong I guess?

```
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import moment from "moment";

const prefix = "cache";
const expiryInMinutes = 10;

const store = async (key, value) => {
  try {
    const item = {
      value,
      timestamp: Date.now(),
    };

    await AsyncStorage.setItem(prefix + key, JSON.stringify(item));
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

const isExpired = (item) => {
  //I corrected Data to Date
  const now = moment(Date.now());
  const storedTime = moment(item.timestamp);

  return now.diff(storedTime, "minutes") > expiryInMinutes;
};

const get = async (key) => {
  try {
    //I added await here
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(prefix + key);
    const item = JSON.parse(value);

    if (!item) return null;

    if (isExpired(item)) {
      await AsyncStorage.removeItem(prefix + key);
      return null;
    }

    return item.value;
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};

export default {
  store,
  get,
};
```

However, it throws that error...
Now I don't know what to do to fix this.
Could you please take a look at my codes and tell me where I got it wrong?
Thank you in advance.

============================================================

After following the advise and introdusing the sugessted codes, it finally successfully got working!

```
import forSaving from "./forSaving";

const obj = { id: 1, word: "This is a word" };
const About = () => {
  useEffect(async () => {
    const storeAndGet = async () => {
      forSaving.store("test", obj);

      const getTest = await forSaving.get("test");
      return getTest;
    };

    const result = await storeAndGet();
    console.log(result);
  }, []);
};

export default About;
```

Oh, this still throws an error saying `Warning: useEffect must not return anything besides a function, which is used for clean-up.`
but I guess this is another story to tackle on

Comment: You have to `await` the result of getItem. And the same thing in the About function, store and get methods are asynchronous so you have to await them too.

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I just tried adding async to the About func and also adding await to both of the functions test and getTest, but it throws another error...

Comment: Ok. Can't do much about that unless you show what you did and what the error is.

Comment: Ah okay, I just edited my post for showing what I did and the error.

Comment: You can't render async content directly. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819864/how-to-async-await-in-react-render-function

Comment: Thanks! I just read that post and I edited my codes and put it onto my post, and now I get the same error as the orignal post had...

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgORY.png

Comment: Thanks for the picture, but still not sure. Could you dumb it down for me?

Comment: There's only one line where you use getItem: `const value = AsyncStorage.getItem(prefix + key);` You have to `await` the value of that operation, just like you do with every AsyncStorage method.

Comment: Now I got it! Sorry I was probably a bit dump. But thank you for the help, which was crucial for this to work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question changed while I was typing this up, and it now includes a different error and two versions of your About function. The original answer mostly still applies, but I'll add that if your `About` function is a React component it needs to return JSX or null, etc.

### Original answer

I think the error is likely due to the fact that your `test` variable is a Promise and you should be passing the literal string `"test"` to the `get()` call:

```js
const getTest = forSaving.get("test");
```

Your `store` function doesn't (explicitly) return anything, so it's not clear what you're expecting your `test` variable to be here:

```js
const test = forSaving.store("test", obj);
```

The next problem you're going to run into is the fact that `get` returns a promise, not a value, so you'd need to wait for it to resolve.

You can solve this using `async/await`:

```js
// async is required to use await
async function About () {
  const obj = { id: 1, word: "This is a word" };

  forSaving.store("test", obj);

  // wait for the promise returned by get()
  // to resolve to a value before proceeding
  const getTest = await forSaving.get("test");
}
```

And finally, you may notice that `get()` doesn't always resolve to the value you just stored. This is because `store()` is also asynchronous and if you don't wait for it to finish its work before calling `get()`, the stored value might not be there yet. Again, the fix is to await `store()` before proceeding:

```js
async function About () {
  const obj = { id: 1, word: "This is a word" };

  // wait for store to finish before continuing
  await forSaving.store("test", obj);

  const getTest = await forSaving.get("test");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping! I just put your codes onto vs code, but now it trhows another error: Render Error
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys
{_X, _Y, _Z, _A}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

Comment: When I wrote the original answer it wasn’t clear that About was a React component. Apply my recommendations to your useEffect version and make the component return some markup.

Comment: It's finally working thanks to your solution! I added the successful codes below on the post. Thank you so much for your help. I appreciate it! My real goal is to be able to use values such as obj of state that I get from the local storage even if users close my app