# Why does console.log in a promise.then() return something different?

Tags: reactjs, promise

In my function, I'm trying to return a value from a promise and pass it to a different component. I can see from the log below that `entries` contains the correct data. But when I try to log the value of calling `getParsedFruit` in my other component, I get `Promise {<pending>}`. I expected the passed value to match what was initially logged, but they seem to be different; any ideas on why this is?

```
   class Produce { 
      getParsedFruit = () => {
          return farmAPI.fetchCrate('fruit').then(apples => {
             const { entries } = getParsedResponse(apples);
             console.log('PARSED:');
             console.log(entries);
             return entries;
          });
       }
      
       render() {
          return (
             <Stand items={this.getParsedFruit()} />
          );
       }
   }
```

And in the `Stand` component, I have a log to see what the passed `items` is:

```
class Stand {
   ...

   render() {
      const { items } = this.props;
      console.log('ITEMS PASSSED TO STAND COMPONENT:');
      console.log(items);
   }
}
```

And for the `getParsedResponse`  function, this is how it's implemented:

```
export const getParsedResponse = (response?: { entries: Array }) => {
    if (!response || !response.entries || !response.entries.length) {
        return { entries: [] };
    }

    const data = response.entries;

    const parsedData: Array<Object> = data
        .map(item => {
            if (!item.source) {
                return null;
            }

            const source = { ...item.source };
    }

    return { entries: parsedData };
};
```

I see that `getParsedResponse` is returning a value and not a promise, so I don't think this is causing the issue.

Comment: Your `getParsedFruit` returns a Promise, so `items={this.getParsedFruit()}` is not going to be what you think. It is literally going to pass a Promise object as `items` property. So you may want an `await` in that assignment.

Comment: You're missing a fundamental part of React... Using and updating *state*.  Don't try to perform asynchronous operations in the `render` function.  The `render` function should just display what's in state.  Invoke the asynchronous operation once when the component first loads (I forget the right way to do that in class components, the hooks equivalent is `useEffect` with an empty dependency array), and in that asynchronous operation you would *update state* with the result.

Comment: See [How to async await in react render function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819864/how-to-async-await-in-react-render-function)

Comment: I see, if I need to call `getParsedFruit` when a different part of the state changes (i.e. if a button is clicked), would I use componentDidUpdate?