# Get value from promise (securestore) to determine what components to render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, promise, expo

I'm storing a user id in Expo's SecureStore, and I need to check if the id exists when the user opens the app. If it exists then that means the user has already registered and can go to the homepage, otherwise the user is new and needs to be onboarded first. I thought this idea was pretty simple, but I have not been able to properly get any value from the promise to determine which flow the user should see.

When I do console.log(id !== null), I get "false" which is correct because the user is new. But then it renders the wrong component. So I feel like using "doesIdExist() ? () : ()" might be the issue, or I'm not actually returning id !== null in check.

```
  const getId = async () => {
    return await SecureStore.getItemAsync('userId');
  }

  const doesIdExist = async () => {
    const id = await getId();
    console.log(id !== null);
    return id!== null;
  }

  return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {doesIdExist() ? (
            <BottomTabNavigator style={styles.tab}/>
        ) : (
            <NavigationContainer>
              <OnboardingNavigator/>
            </NavigationContainer>
        )}
      </View>
  );
```

Comment: `doesIdExist()` always returns a promise. And that is an object. Objects are truthy.

Comment: @trincot How could I get it to return a value (id) instead of a promise? x_x

Comment: You should not have asynchronous code in your render function. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53819864/how-to-async-await-in-react-render-function)

Comment: You can also apply the [`usePromise`](https://github.com/capaj/react-promise) hook to wait for the `doesIdExist` promise to be resolved.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how you would use usePromise here?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be to use [SplashScreen](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/splash-screen/). The splash screen to remain visible until it has been explicitly told to hide.

A simple solution:

```
const App = () => {
  const [appReady, setAppReady] = useState(false)
  const [exist, setExist] = useState(false)

  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      const id = await SecureStore.getItemAsync('userId')
      setExist(id !== null)
      setAppReady(true)
    })()
  }, [])

  const onLayout = useCallback(async () => {
    if (appReady) {
      await SplashScreen.hideAsync();
    }
  }, [appIsReady]);

  if (!appReady) return null

  return (
    <View style={styles.container} onLayout={onLayout}>
      {exist ? (
        <BottomTabNavigator style={styles.tab} />
      ) : (
        <NavigationContainer>
          <OnboardingNavigator />
        </NavigationContainer>
      )}
    </View>
  )
}
```